# How do I use rxjs map to mutate data in object before casting a new type from an object gotten from a HttpClient request?

Tags: json, angular, dictionary, rxjs, httpclient

Hope the title isn't too specific.

The back-end I am working with returns Dates as a string. I have a function to convert that string to a javascript Date object. I use a Rxjs map to convert the json response to my Typescript objects like so.

```
  getAllRecordsByEmployeeId(employeeId: number): Observable<Record[]> {
    return this.http.get<Record[]>(
        this.basePath
        + this.recordPath
        + this.recordEmployeeIdParam
        + employeeId,
        this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            map((res: any) => res.records as Record[]),
        );
  }
```

I want to mutate res.records.startDate with a function before it gets turned into a Record object. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getAllRecordsByEmployeeId(employeeId: number): Observable<Record[]> {
    return this.http.get<Record[]>(
```

I understand, that your http request does not actually return a `Record` array. It returns an object with a `Record` Array field, which is basically another Record model. It is very similar, but it's a different model.

Please consider changing it to:

```
interface RecordFromApi extends Record {
  startDate: string; // overwrite attribute
}

interface RecordResponse {
  records: RecordFromApi[];
}

getAllRecordsByEmployeeId(employeeId: number): Observable<Record[]> {
    return this.http.get<RecordResponse>(
        this.basePath
        + this.recordPath
        + this.recordEmployeeIdParam
        + employeeId,
        this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            map((res: RecordResponse) => res.records.map(record => mapRecord(record))), // mapRecord is a custom function which maps RecordFromApi model to Record model
        );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great idea and will vastly increase the quality of my code!

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar in my application. But instead of returning

```js
res.records as Record[]
```

we do something like this:

```js
.pipe(
      map((records: Record[]) => records.map(records => new Record(record)))
);
```

and then on the `record.ts`

```js
export class Record {
  /*
    properties
  */
  date: Date;

  constructor(params: Partial<Record> = {}) {
    this.date = new Date(params.date);
  }
}
```

This way you actually get instances of your class and you can use any functions you may have in your class (that's the issue we had when we came up with this solution).